# Android Two different type object arraylist add into single arraylist

Tags: java

I try to add two arraylist into single arraylist. all arraylist object type is different.

here my two arraylist-

```
     ArrayList<NewsItem> topnewslist=new ArrayList<>();
     ArrayList<LatestNewsInfo> latestnewslist=new ArrayLis();

     ArrayList<AllNewsInfo> allnewslist=new ArrayList<>();// add here

    // I try this
   allnewslist.addAll(topnewslist); // not add bcoz differnt type of object
  allnewslist.addAll(latestnewslist); //not add bcoz differnt type of object
```

// Note: all object data model value is same.

What is best solution for this??

Comment: `ArrayList<Object> allnewslist=new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: thanks for your feedback. i also try this but when i display all data into listview . then face a problem to set data base of position in adapter class.

Comment: Main prob is values ovver right.  allnewslist.addAll(topnewslist);  allnewslist.addAll(latestnewslist);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ArrayList<Object> allnewslist=new ArrayList<>();`.

Ideally both `NewsItem` and `LatestNewsInfo` should inherit common interface, and then you can have the list of this interface.

```
interface News{}  //can be an abstract class

class NewsItem implements News{
}

class LatestNewsInfo implements News{
}

//edit - define variables to interface instead of actual implementation object 
List<News> allnewslist=new ArrayList<>();
```